# Change age in Google Account

Tags: google-account

I've looked on the internet and it says you can change the age in your Google account if you have a credit card. I entered my DOB incorrectly—it says I'm a year younger than I am.

However, I can’t find any page to enter any card or verification details.

Answer (score 2):

From [Edit your Google Account information - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en)

> ## Edit your basic account information
>
> You can edit information like your name, the email and phone number associated with your account,
> and your birthday. This basic information is used to help others get
> in touch with you more easily in products like Hangouts, Gmail, and
> Maps.
>
> 1. Sign in to [My Account](http://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. In the "Personal info & privacy" section, select Your personal info.
> 3. Choose the information you want to edit and follow the onscreen instructions.
>
> Note: The email and phone number here are used to help identify you
> and help you keep in touch. They are not the same as your [recovery
> phone number and email
> address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183723), which
> help you get back into your account if you forget your password.